# Did SendMessage has sent custom message?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

I'm using code below to send message to main thread dialog window:

```
SendMessage(AuthMsgHWND,WM_AUTHORISE_MESSAGE, (WPARAM)&params,0);
```

Because of unknown reason sometimes main window didn't get message and `SendMessage` imediatly returns. Is it possible somehow to know was `SendMessage` successful?

Comment: Did you read the documentation for the function you are calling?

Comment: Yes, but not found much useful. "The return value specifies the result of the message processing; it depends on the message sent." So how it depends?

Comment: The recipient returns a value to you. What do the docs for that message say? Or is it a custom message of your making?

Comment: this is custom message

Comment: The likely explanation is that the window handle that you pass is incorrect, or that your code is defective.

Comment: Looks like I have the same error before calling SendMessage. But when last error is cleared when?

Comment: `GetLastError` is only valid when the result of the function call indicates a failure, or in the few instances that are called out in the documentation. Are you marshalling that parameter? Windows only does it for you in the case of system messages. (`0` to `(WM_USER-1)`) Is the process you're sending the message to at equal or lesser integrity?

Comment: maybe use `postmessage`, sendmessage would call the message handler in current thread, since you are sending message to the main thread from another thread.